# Natural action of a group on associated lie algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

Take $G$ a linear algebraic group or a lie group. Let be $\mathfrak{g}$ the lie algebra generated by $G$. I would like to know if there is a natural action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ and if there is a geometrical interpretation in the same sense of $\mathfrak{g}=$tangent space in the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There certainly is in the form of the [adjoint action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) (confusingly, this can refer to a few different things).

The quick summary is this: a Lie group $G$ acts on itself by conjugation. That is, $g\cdot h=ghg^{-1}$. The advantage of this (compared to the left multiplication action, for example) is that any $g\in G$ fixes the identity since $geg^{-1}=e$. Thus every $g\in G$ gives a diffeomorphism of $G$ taking fixing $e$, and the differential is therefore a linear isomorphism $\mathfrak g\to\mathfrak g$ (where $\mathfrak g=T_eG$). This gives the adjoint representation $\operatorname{Ad}\colon G\to \operatorname{Aut}\mathfrak g$.

A priori this would be difficult to compute, but it turns out that, if $G$ is a matrix group, then an element $h\in\mathfrak g$ can also be written as a matrix, and $\operatorname{Ad}g$ acts on $h$ as $ghg^{-1}$. This fact is pretty magical to me, as it does not seem at all obvious at first.

Comment: Thanks... Can I ask you if do you know if given $B$ a subgroup of $G$ then $B$ acts on $\mathfrak{g}$ in the same way? The adjoint action on $\mathfrak{b}$ can be extended?

Comment: @LuckyS definitely if $B$ is normal, but I’m not sure if any converse holds

Comment: Ok, I think that for my problem it's sufficient.

Comment: @LuckyS One can compose the adjoint action $\operatorname{Ad}:G\to\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ with the the inclusion map $\iota:B\to G$ to obtain a canonical representation $\operatorname{Ad}\circ\iota:B\to\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ for any subgroup $B\le G$.

Comment: @Kajelad ah of course; thank you.